# ¿Cómo puedo reemplazar outliers con R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo un set de datos con varias columnas a los que he aplicado un boxplot (a una sola columna como muestra que he llamado serie2) y estoy usando la siguiente fórmula para reemplazarlos según un parámetro:

```
outliersReplace <- function(serie2){

  Q  <- quantile(serie2)
  minimo <- Q[1]
  Q1     <- Q[2]
  Me     <- Q[3]
  Q3     <- Q[4]
  maximo <- Q[5]
  IQR    <- Q3 - Q1

  lowLimit  <- max(minimo, Q1 - 1.5*IQR)
  highLimit <- min(maximo, Q3 + 1.5*IQR)

  df[serie2] > highLimit <- Me
  df[serie2] < lowLimit <- Me

  serie2
}
```

Sin embargo no logro reemplazarlos y me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Error in `*tmp*`[serie2] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Hay alguna forma para ajustar mi fórmula para que haga lo que pido, y de paso que sea funcional para cualquier cantidad de columnas que contenga mi set de datos?

Desde ya les agradezco (soy nuevo en esto!)

Comment: Hola @Juan Jose. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. Podrias agregar una muestra de tus datos? Puedes [edit] para hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estas buscando lo puedes conseguir de la siguiente manera

```
outliersReplace <- function(serie2){

  Q  <- quantile(serie2)
  minimo <- Q[1]
  Q1     <- Q[2]
  Me     <- Q[3]
  Q3     <- Q[4]
  maximo <- Q[5]
  IQR    <- Q3 - Q1

  lowLimit  <- max(minimo, Q1 - 1.5*IQR)
  highLimit <- min(maximo, Q3 + 1.5*IQR)

  serie2[serie2 > highLimit] <- Me
  serie2[serie2 < lowLimit] <- Me

  serie2

}



df<-iris[1:30,1:4]
head(df)

#Usarlo en un columna
outliersReplace(df$Sepal.Length)

#Ejemplo de como aplicarlo a todas las columnas de un df
apply(df,1,outliersReplace)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Rolando!
La función `apply` fue la que me salvo de hacer el cálculo columna por columna.

Answer (score 1):

El error:

> Error in `*tmp*`[serie2] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Si bien no es del todo exacto, nos da un dato importante, nos habla de un "closure", que no es más que un tipo especial de función, pero en definitiva una función y lo que nos está diciendo es que una función no es indexable, algo obvio, una lista, un vector, etc son indexables, una función no.

El problema es, podríamos decir que tipográfico, te has equivocado en esto:

```
df[serie2] > highLimit <- Me
df[serie2] < lowLimit <- Me
```

Entiendo que quisiste hacer algo así:

```
serie2[serie2 > highLimit | serie2[serie2] < lowLimit] <- Me
```

Claramente `df` no existe en el contexto de tu función, pero si existe en el contexto de R aunque constantemente tratemos de ignorando nombrando cualquier `data.frame` como `df` y es que `df()` es una función `The F Distribution` de ahí el error que estas teniendo.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación. En el momento de nombrar el dataframe no me pasó por la cabeza el contexto que utiliza R para ejecutar el código. Con este cambio la función hace lo que necesito.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda!